# What is the disintegration of joint distribution w.r.t. the first coordinate?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\delta_x$ be the Dirac measure on a point $x$. Let $\pi=\frac{1}{3}(\delta_{(1,0)}+\delta_{(1,1)}+\delta_{(2,2)})$ be a given probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\pi$ has the marginals $\mu=\frac{2}{3}\delta_1+\frac{1}{3}\delta_2$ and $\nu=\frac{1}{3}\delta_0+\frac{1}{3}\delta_1+\frac{1}{3}\delta_2$.

If $\pi$ has a $\mu$-a.s. unique disintegration w.r.t. the first coordinate denoted by $\pi_{x_1}$ such that $\pi(dx,dy)=\mu(dx)K(x,dy)$  which $K(⋅,⋅)$ is the transition probability kernel.

Why do we have
$$\pi_{x_1}={1\over 2}(\delta_{0}+\delta_{1})$$ if $x_1=1$;

And $\pi_{x_1}=\delta_{2}$ if $x_1=2$; and $\pi_{x_1}=0$ otherwise?

Comment: Are deltas Dirac's deltas?

Comment: @paperskilltrees Yes!

Comment: What do you think it should be, otherwise?

Comment: @BrianTung That means for $x_1=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{1,2\}$, $\pi_{x_1}=0$.